# Connection to remote MS SQL database from Linux server using PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, database, database-connection

I have hosted my website on Linux server and I want to connect MS SQL database. i have used PHP in programming. I have contacted to both server provider and they helped in their extent. But my issue is not solved Can you guide me what to do. My code is below.

While I run this it is showing " could not find driver1"

Please guide me. Thanks in advance

```
<?php 

//echo phpinfo();

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>testing</h1>
</body>
</html>

<?php
// Server in the this format: <computer>\<instance name> or 
// <server>,<port> when using a non default port number
$server = 'server:port';
$myDB = "DatabaseName";

// Connect to MSSQL
$link = mssql_connect($server, 'username', 'password');

if (!$link) {
    die('Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL');
}
else
{
 echo "success";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

try {

    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server='server_name';Database=database_name", 'username', 'password');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

} catch (Exception $e) {

    die(print_r($e->getMessage() ));
}

$tsql = "select * from table_name";
$getResults = $conn->prepare($tsql);
$getResults->execute();
$results = $getResults->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);

foreach ($results as $row) {
  echo $row['0'].' '.$row['6'];
  echo "<br>";
}


?>
```

Comment: Thanks @Rony for help